# Exploding a large json-file using ijson

Tags: python, json, ijson

I have a large json-file (too large to fit in memory) with the following structure:

```
{
    "commonVal": "foo",
    "entries": [
        { "bar": "baz1" },
        { "bar": "baz2" },
        ...,
    ]
}
```

I would like to process this json file as objects like this:

```
commonVal: foo, bar: baz1
commonVal: foo, bar: baz2
...
```

I.e.

1. Read `commonVal` (outside of the list) and store that in a variable,
2. Iterate over `entries` one by one

To my help I have the [`ijson`](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) library.

I can perform step 1 using `kvitems`, and step 2 using `items`, but I can't figure out how to "mix" the two. (I would very much like to avoid dropping to the events-api because the entries in the list are more complex than in the example.)

Comment: *too large to fit in memory* - how large?

Comment: The first file I encountered that OOMed was 1.6GB

Comment: Because of the size of the file, you may have more control by writing your own text parser, especially if it has the simple structure you showed in your example.

Comment: Text parser? You mean json-parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ijson.parse`, hopefully in combination with the [event interception mechanism](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/#intercepting-events).

`ijson.parse` will allow you to iterate over every single event in the JSON file. Using this you should be able to both read the common data, and identify when your big list starts. You can then forward the rest of the results to `ijson.items`.

Check the example in the [event interception mechanism](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/#intercepting-events) doc, with some simple modifications it really should be pretty much what you need.